# Web Application - Reactjs - It is possible to make a great score on SEO with exclusively client side rendering's Web application in 2018?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I so much love the flow of client-side applications, but wonder if it possible to make great SEO with that. That what I ask if in 2018, it is possible to make an as well SEO on client side rendering exclusively ?

I know there is some topics on this subject but the answers are very olds regarding the evolution of technology.

I have heard about Gatsby.js. The difficulty is that, after testing it for few days, maybe I'm wrong but seems Gatsby can't access to backend when building application. Hence it's would be difficut to build some specific features as socket.io or other thing similaries.

Any hint would be great, 
thanks

Comment: If you want server side rendering and a backend with a websocket connection etc., then [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) might be worth looking into. If you have a more [JAM stack](https://jamstack.org/) oriented project, you can use Gatsby like you mentioned or e.g. [react-static](https://github.com/nozzle/react-static).

Comment: Hey, I want just a client side rendering with great SEO is my only wish. Also Gatsby seems to be recalcitrant to install some features on backend like soket.io due to the fact Gatsby works only on front end it seems.

Comment: Client side rendering with great SEO is very hard, if not impossible, to achieve I'm afraid. E.g. open graph tags used for sharing on Facebook, Twitter, etc. does not work with client side rendering alone.

Comment: I see Tholle, Thanks, maybe there is site generators that allow to work on the backend ?

Comment: Yes, you can still use websockets and regular APIs at runtime with tools like Gatsby and react-static. You can see them more as tools for making as much as you can static, and the rest can be dynamic.

Comment: Okay so if I understand you well, you say that is possible to work on the backend  with Gatsby, as a tool which is more an optimizer than a full static framework ? Newbie question I know

Comment: Yes, you can build "hybrid" Gatsby apps which have both static content and gets live data from your backend on runtime. [This is explained here in the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/).

Comment: Okay, very interesting

Comment: a question please, when you say "websockets and regular APIs"  you mean that library like Socket.io are difficult to work with Gatsby but built-in functionalities can works if I understand you ?

Comment: There should be no problem to connect with a websocket with a server in e.g. a component's `componentDidMount` when using Gatsby.